I can't display graphics in different URLs
first of all I would like to apologize for my lack of knowledge and because I don't know if I know how to express the problem or if this is the right place.
I have an altruistic web page with some graphs of meteorological variables.
https://www.meteoensevilla.es/wxcustom-charts.php
The graphs are displayed correctly with this URL, but they do not do so when it is:
https://meteoensevilla.es/wxcustom-charts.php
I do not have the necessary knowledge for the following instructions, someone helped me:
// Get data from the Temperature and Dew Point CSV file
data: {
csvURL: 'https://www.meteoensevilla.es/customfiles/T2.csv',
startColumn: 0, // Start column has the times
endColumn: 2, //Column 1 is temperature, column 2 is dewpoint, and column 3 is heat index
}

If I remove the www, then the second URL works for me but the first one will stop working.
Is there a solution for this? I hope I have explained myself well?
Thanks in advance
Sorry, my limited knowledge doesn't leave me much room for testing.

Try leaving the protocol and host out of the url csv URL and use just /customfiles/T2.csv. Depending on how it's used, many systems will interpret such URLs as relative to the current host and work just right.

CORS error only occuring when url is prefixed with www
